# Where to change the "From" settings?

Tags: thunderbird

In the Thunderbird account settings I've specified the following:

```
Your name: John Doe (My Company Name)
Mail address: info@mydomain.com
Reply-To: info@mydomain.com
Outgoing server: Use Standard Server
```

Outgoing Servers (SMTP):

```
Google Mail: smtp.gmail.com (Standard)
Description: Google Mail
Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
User Name: johndoe@gmail.com
Authentification: Password, normal
Connection Security: SSL/TLS
```

When I send an email using this server, my name is displayed in Thunderbird as

```
From: John Doe (My Company Name) <johndoe@googlemail.com> (<-- the recipient should not see this, he should see "info@mydomain.com" instead)
Subject: Some Test Mail to check my name
Reply To: Me <info@mydomain.com>
```

Why is my gmail address displayed to the user, and how would I change that?

Comment: Do you have a business account?

Comment: I use Virtual Identity to be able to change the from address to anything I want. But note, your mail will no longer pass a SPF check, so it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why is my gmail address displayed to the user, and how would I change that?

Your from address is set by gmail, because you are using their SMTP server.

To change the from address:

> **Send emails from a different address or alias**
>
> If you own another email address, you can send mail as that address.
> For example:
>
> - Yahoo, Outlook, or other non-Gmail address
> - Your work, school, or business domain or alias, like @yourschool.edu or youralias@gmail.com
> - Another Gmail address
>
> **1. Add an address you own**
>
> - On your computer, open Gmail.
> - In the top right, click Settings and then Settings.
> - Click the Accounts and Import or Accounts tab.
> - In the "Send mail as" section, click Add another email address.
> - Enter your name and the address you want to send from.
> - Click Next Step.
> - Enter the SMTP server (for example, smtp.gmail.com or smtp.yourschool.edu) and the username and password on that account.
> - Click Add Account.
>
> **2. Confirm the address**
>
> - Sign in to the account you added.
> - Open the confirmation message you got from Gmail.
> - Click the link.
>
> **3. Change the "From" address**
>
> - In the message, click the "From" line.
>   (If you don't see this, click the space next to the recipient's email.)
> - Select the address to send from.

Source [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)